# Scrolling down causes chrome to crash

Tags: google-chrome, mouse-scroll, 14.10

I've just installed 14.10.

In Chrome, whenever I try to scroll down using the mouse wheel the browser closes.

It doesn't happen if I'm using Firefox, but I prefer Chrome.

Is there a way to fix this bug?

Comment: Immediately after I posted that comment, I tried again and it is now working properly.  I'll update again if it comes back

Comment: It seems to happen only on the google results page

Comment: Hmm odd... What about bing / duckduckgo results?

Comment: I have it only if I working more than one chrome-Profile

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by increasing the number of open files.

Update /etc/security/limits.conf

```
* hard nofile 65535
* soft nofile 65535
```